# Comparing year over year data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am wanting to pull data for a date range in 2017 then pull the same date range but for 2016.  I thought I would get crafty and use `DateAdd()` feature, but I am missing something here as I get an error of

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What I want to do is get a `COUNT(saledate)` that fall between the time period which will give me the number of sales.  This is sample DDL

```
Declare @startdate varchar(100), @enddate varchar(100), @prevyrstartdate varchar(100), @prevyrenddate varchar(100)

SET @startdate = '01/01/2017'
SET @enddate = '01/31/2017'
SET @prevyrstartdate = CAST(DateAdd(yy, -1, @startdate) As Date)
Set @prevyrenddate = CAST(DateAdd(yy, -1, @enddate) As Date)

Declare @HoldingPattern Table
(
    salesman varchar(100)
    ,saledate date
)

Insert Into @HoldingPattern (salesman, saledate) VALUES
('BOB', '2017-01-23')
,('BOB', '2017-01-30')
,('BOB', '2017-01-24')
,('BOB', '2017-01-30')
,('BOB', '2017-01-30')
,('BOB', '2017-01-30')
,('BOB', '2017-02-30')
,('BOB', '2017-02-27')
,('BOB', '2017-03-31')
,('BOB', '2017-03-27')
,('BOB', '2016-01-23')
,('BOB', '2016-01-30')
,('BOB', '2016-01-24')
,('BOB', '2016-01-30')
,('BOB', '2016-03-30')
,('BOB', '2016-03-30')
,('BOB', '2016-03-30')
,('BOB', '2016-02-27')
,('BOB', '2016-02-31')
,('BOB', '2016-02-27')


Select
salesman
,[2017 Data] = (Select COUNT(CAST(saledate As nvarchar(100))) FROM @HoldingPattern where saledate between @startdate AND @enddate)
,[2016 Data] = (Select COUNT(CAST(saledate As nvarchar(100))) FROM @HoldingPattern where saledate between @prevyrstartdate and @prevyrstartdate)
FROM @HoldingPattern
```

Comment: Why are you using unsafe formats like `m/d/yyyy`? Why are you using lazy shorthand like `yy` instead of typing `YEAR`? Why are you declaring your variables as `varchar`instead of, I don't know, `date`?

Comment: You have angered Aaron Bertrand. Repent! Read these articles: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand - 2009-10-16](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)  and [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand - 2011-09-20](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) and then repent again!

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I have always used `mm/dd/yyyy` format, old habits die hard since that was the 1st formatting I used.  I thought `yy` was the way to go, even looking at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) it makes me think so.  Long term result parameters will be passed in from a .NET application and I have always had more success declaring as 'varchar`

Comment: More success = ignoring bugs, probably. Anyway your sample data has a real problem: `2017-02-30` is not a date at least on this planet.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yes, I used Feb and Mar 2017 as sample data.  I extracted roughly 10 dates from my actual data, then just changed the month & year to make it work for this example.  I did not mean to anger.  Will def read articles posted by SqlZim

Comment: Nobody's angry, I was asking serious questions.

Comment: @MichaelMormon - thanks for taking the time to create a well defined question.  For future reference, adding expected output really helps us understand the requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bad data, bad data types, and bad formatting aside, if you're getting a month of data for present and previous year, you don't need to have four variables; one will do. But it should be a date, not a string. I also recommend avoiding `BETWEEN` since it only works in an extremely narrow set of circumstances.

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '20170101';

DECLARE @HoldingPattern TABLE
(
  salesman varchar(100),
  saledate date
);

-- let's ignore the illogical dates
INSERT @HoldingPattern (salesman, saledate) VALUES
 ('BOB', '20170123'),('BOB', '20170130'),('BOB', '20170124'),
 ('BOB', '20170130'),('BOB', '20170130'),('BOB', '20170130'),
 /*('BOB', '20170230'),*/('BOB', '20170227'),('BOB', '20170331'),
 ('BOB', '20170327'),('BOB', '20160123'),('BOB', '20160130'),
 ('BOB', '20160124'),('BOB', '20160130'),('BOB', '20160330'),
 ('BOB', '20160330'),('BOB', '20160330'),('BOB', '20160227'),
 /*('BOB', '20160231'),*/('BOB', '20160227');

SELECT
  Salesman,
  [2017 Data] = COUNT(CASE WHEN saledate >= @startdate 
    AND saledate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startdate) THEN 1 END),
  [2016 Data] = COUNT(CASE WHEN saledate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @startdate) 
    AND saledate < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startdate)) THEN 1 END)
FROM @HoldingPattern
GROUP BY Salesman;
```

Result:

```
Salesman    2017 Data    2016 Data
--------    ---------    ---------
BOB         6            4
```

Further reading:

- [#BackToBasics : Dating Responsibly](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)
- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand the question; but I see 9 sales for 2016 and 9 for 2017?

Comment: @Max not all in the same month - scroll to the right on the original question to see the where clause limits to January only.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand the requirements, this looks like a simple pivot query to me.

As @AaronBertrand notes, it is far superior to use the correct data type, and I've done so as well.

```
DECLARE @startdate date
    , @enddate date
    , @prevyrstartdate date
    , @prevyrenddate date;

SET @startdate = '2017-01-01';
SET @enddate = '2017-01-31';
SET @prevyrstartdate = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @startdate);
SET @prevyrenddate = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @enddate);

DECLARE @HoldingPattern TABLE
(
    salesman varchar(100) NOT NULL
    , saledate date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @HoldingPattern (salesman, saledate) 
VALUES ('BOB', '2017-01-23')
        , ('BOB', '2017-01-30')
        , ('BOB', '2017-01-24')
        , ('BOB', '2017-01-30')
        , ('BOB', '2017-01-30')
        , ('BOB', '2017-01-30')
        --, ('BOB', '2017-02-30')
        , ('BOB', '2017-02-27')
        , ('BOB', '2017-03-31')
        , ('BOB', '2017-03-27')
        , ('BOB', '2016-01-23')
        , ('BOB', '2016-01-30')
        , ('BOB', '2016-01-24')
        , ('BOB', '2016-01-30')
        , ('BOB', '2016-03-30')
        , ('BOB', '2016-03-30')
        , ('BOB', '2016-03-30')
        , ('BOB', '2016-02-27')
        --, ('BOB', '2016-02-31')
        , ('BOB', '2016-02-27');
```

Here is the [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).  I'm adding a single day to each end-date so I can use a "less than" comparison, which would really only make a difference if `saledate` had a time component:

```
SELECT pvt.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , SaleYear = DATEPART(YEAR, hp.saledate)
    FROM @HoldingPattern hp
    WHERE (hp.saledate >= @startdate AND hp.saledate <= @enddate)
        OR (hp.saledate >= @prevyrstartdate AND hp.saledate <= @prevyrenddate)
    ) src
PIVOT (
    COUNT(src.saledate)
    FOR src.SaleYear  IN (
        [2016]
        , [2017]
    )
) pvt;
```

The results:

```
+----------+------+------+
| salesman | 2016 | 2017 |
+----------+------+------+
| BOB      |    4 |    6 |
+----------+------+------+
```

By the way, Aaron's methodology *is* slightly faster; I just wanted to add another way of getting to the same output.

Comment: Certainly, and if it were for more than two months or multiple years, I would probably lean toward pivot as well, unless at scale the more verbose approach was faster there too. Logically they should amount to the same thing, but it's always valuable to test when anything changes (data, index, optimizer).